# SwiftUI NavigationSplitView sidebar button location

Tags: macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to use the new `NavigationSplitView` in SwiftUI but somehow, the Sibebar button renders differently between a `Mac` and `Mac Catalyst`

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    } detail: {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
    }
}
```

With Mac, the Sidebar Button renders on the toolbar
[image]

With Mac Catalyst, it renders on the sidebar. My `Mac Catalyst Interface` is already set to `Optimize for Mac`
[image]

I'm wondering if this is just a bug in `Mac Catalyst`?

or if not, how can I make the `Mac Catalyst` sidebar button show like the `Mac` build? I've already experimented with `.toolbarRole` but it seems it has no effect on the sidebar button.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with the difference. It's just that the sample of Mac Catalyst apps on the WWDC22 demo videos also have their Sidebar button icon placed on the toolbar, which makes me think this might be a bug, or I'm missing something in my configuration.

Comment: Not a bug, it is design. If you go to Your Target>General there are different versions of generating Mac apps. You are likely using the "Designed for iPad" version. There is a Mac version for Catalyst.

Comment: yes, I'm using `Mac Catalyst` rather than `Designed for iPad` and also use `Optimize for Mac` and not `Scaled to Match iPad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest macOS and Xcode Beta 4, Mac Catalyst now properly displays the sidebar button:

[image]

It was a bug after all.